# Send Image in WhatsApp Web with Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, copy-paste, whatsapp, html5-clipboard-api

I need to send an image to WhatsApp Web with the Chrome extension. I use only JS and HTML.

I currently use the Clipboard API to convert an image from input file to base64 to copy the image to the clipboard.

But I need to do the paste functionality.

I already tried simulating CTRL+V with JS but it doesn't work.

I want to know if I can continue with this way of doing it or is there another alternative.

[Function to copy image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ux8f.png)

I don't know how to paste the image and see it like this.

[paste image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFA4K.png)